# Why don't edits in math show up "rendered"?

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits, latex

When looking at suggested edits that involve changes to LaTeX code, I can't see the rendered output, only the code.  E.g. I was looking at the suggested edits for https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/177437.

It would be much easier to approve or reject if I could see the LaTeX code worked out as it would be when the question is displayed, but this doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: @whuber I am not so sure: latex rendering is working on only very few SE sites. This might be as good a place to discuss this as any. I would check if it was discussed on Math.SE Meta though. Should we tag it as [feature-request]? I don't think this qualifies as a "bug". The rationale is clear: suggested edits interface highlights all the changes, and it's not easily possible to highlight changes inside a rendered formula. But one could request a feature of rendering the formula and highlighting *the whole formula* in such cases.

Comment: Good thoughts, @amoeba.  I still maintain that any feature common to more than one SE site really is an SE feature and so ought to be discussed on Meta SE.  That's where one is more likely to attract the attention of people who could actually do something about the issue.

Comment: OK, then I will ask this there.

Comment: @PeterFlom no need, it has been migrated now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard He was the one who migrated it.